# Issues with installing R on Centos 7

Tags: r, centos7

I'm trying to install R on my CentOS 7 by...

```
yum install epel-release
yum install R
```

but i keep seeing this error at end of installing R

```
....
Error: Package: R-core-3.2.3-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.2.3-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)

 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I can't figure out what this error means...
What can i do for solving this problem?
or am i missing something with my procedure?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/628562/upgrade-r-to-3-1-1-on-ec2-via-yum

Answer (score 0):

Download the lib64icu42-4.2.1-1mdv2010.0.x86_64.rpm from the below link:
ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/Mandriva/official/2010.0/x86_64/media/main/release/lib64icu42-4.2.1-1mdv2010.0.x86_64.rpm

Install the RPM:

```
sudo rpm -ivh lib64icu42-4.2.1-1mdv2010.0.x86_64.rpm
```

This could help solving the error. Thanks!

rpm link:
https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)